# Django: Cannot assign "'Emma'": "Booking.boat" must be a "Boat" instance

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have been trying to make boat reservation system.

```
# models.py
class Boat(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField (max_length=10, unique=True, blank=False)
    type = models.CharField (max_length=10, blank=False)

class Booking(models.Model):
    date_from = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    date_to = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    rent = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)  
    boat = models.ForeignKey(Boat, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

A new boat is registered through this form:

```
class newBoatform(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label='Name of the boat: ', max_length=15)
    type = forms.CharField(label='Type of the boat: ', max_length=15)
  class Meta:
      model = Boat
      fields = ('name','type',)
```

A boat is booked through this form:

```
class bookform(forms.Form):
    boat =forms.CharField(label='Select boat',max_length=15)
    date_from=forms.DateField(label='Date from', initial=date.today)
    date_to=forms.DateField(label='Date to')
    rent = forms.DecimalField(label='Pay $ ')
  class Meta:
      model = Booking
      fields = ('date_from','date_to','rent','boat','person',)
```

To book a boat through the *bookform*, I am inserting an existing boat name and other field information. Then I am getting the error:
**Cannot assign "'Emma'": "Booking.boat" must be a "Boat" instance.**

The view function of the *bookform*:

```
def bookBoat(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = bookform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = Booking()
            obj.boat = form.cleaned_data['boat']
            obj.date_from = form.cleaned_data['date_from']
            obj.date_to = form.cleaned_data['date_to']
            obj.rent = form.cleaned_data['rent']
            obj.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
    else:
        form = bookform()
    return render(request, 'booking.html', {'form': form})
```

I can't understand what is wrong. Other answers on this same error are going over my head.

Comment: How are you supposed to assign a string (`CharField`) to a `ForeignKey` field?

Comment: Ok, I got the point. It can't be a CharField as it's a ForeignKey.  Now how do i implement it in the right manner?

Answer (score 0):

As I can't comment here's my suggestion: `obj.boat = Boat.objects.get(name=form.cleaned_data['boat'])`

That should do the job.